# Difference between php.ini Configuration File location and Loaded configuration file?

Tags: php

What is the difference between configuration file and loaded configuration file?

If ini file is loaded from "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini ", what does ini inside C:\Windows mean?

Output of phpinfo()

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows 
Loaded Configuration File C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
```

If i have to change some config, should i modify both files?

Comment: I have noticed on Windows that I can not get the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" to change, even when I set PHPRC=c:\somepath\php.ini.  But since the Loaded one is the only one that matters, this is just another piece of information to absorb and move on from, since PHP doesn't use C:\Windows\php.ini when another one is shown in "Loaded"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Configuration File (php.ini) Path" is where by default php.ini should be/PHP will look for by default (this path is may be the %windir env var for Win distro?).

I believe that in your apache config you have PHPINIDir, that define explicitly a new path to the ini file. If you don't have php.ini in there, then PHP defaults will be used (even if you have php.ini in the C:\Windows folder). At least this is the case when PHP is used as module (which is my config and I'm able to test on).

So "Loaded Configuration File" is your currently loaded config file and the one you should edit.

Comment: might add for future reference that `<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>` will give you the current `ìni` used in case of multiple references ( like `.user.ini` or a folder based `php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

The Loaded Configuration File is the correct one. Not sure what the other is supposed to mean. Change the Loaded one.

Also is there really a php.ini file in C:\Windows? I guess not.

Comment: Yup, some Windows Web Server bundles (Apache, PHP..) put a configuration file in C:\Windows, sometimes it IS the effective one.

Comment: Could someone clarify why this comment is so heavily downvoted? Is it incorrect? I'm looking for my php.ini also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on WS 2008 R2 with IIS. 
Loaded config file was allways from program files/php/php.ini, but i needed php.ini from WAMP server (c:/wamp/php/...)
I try to find from where it points to program files. after a while i just tried to rename the php.ini in programfiles (like deleted or missing) and after restarting WAMP services I get the right php.ini from C:/wamp/... :)
also I must delete cokies from IE to make the website work.